# Cache curl response

Tags: php, caching, curl

I would like to cache curl responses, and I found out a couple of ways to do that, but all of them include saving a response to the file, and than retrieving it. The problem here is that my code needs to work with `curl_getinfo()` object, which is available only after the curl_exec call is finished. So, the ideal way would be if the curl itself would cache the response instead of making a new request. I tried that approach using `Cache-Control` request header with the value `max-age=604800`, however I don't see any changes. Any ideas how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough information about a request to compile a unique identifier/key you could use for example [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php):

```
$key = $url.':'.$some_other_variable;
$cached = $memcached->get($key);
if ($cached)
{
    return $cached;
}

// Perform cURL request
// ...

$memcached->set($key, $data_to_cache);
```